# How to IgnoreNulls for function ATR?

Tags: activex, teechart

For ExpMovAvg, there is the code  TChart1.Series(1).FunctionType.asExpMovAvg.IgnoreNulls = True  to ignore the nulls, but for ATR, I didn't find anything after FunctionType (There is FunctionType.asADX for ADX,but nothing for ATR), so how to do that for ATR, thanks.   (I use Teechart2011 Eval & VB6)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the IgnoreNulls property doesn't exist for this function type. Since TeeChart ActiveX is a wrapper from TeeChart VCL version, I've added it to the VCL wish list to be implemented in next versions (TV52016368).

In the meanwhile, the only way I can think of to achieve the same is to completely remove the null points from the *source* series.

Comment: My tremendous appreciations for your quick and in time reply!!